# How to say "I'm happy to be here right now"

Tags: translation

How to say "I'm happy to be here right now". This is my guess:

> わたしはすごくうれしい、いまここにがいるから.

Comment: わたしは今ここにいるのが楽しい.

Comment: I'd say this: 僕は今、ここにいられて嬉しい

Comment: Can you provide context? How formal do you want to sound? What's the speaker's gender? The translation would largely depend on that.

Comment: If possible I'd like to know both casual and formal ways of saying it, since I am currently in the learning process and would like to compare the two.
As for gender, if you could show me the difference between speaking to a male and female it would be useful too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

> [今]{いま}、ここにいられて[嬉]{うれ}しいです。 ← polite
>   今、ここにいられて嬉しい。 ← casual

いられる (lit. "can be") is the potential form of the verb いる(居る), "to be (somewhere) / to exist".
いられて is the te-form of いられる. The て joins the two clauses いられる and うれしい, and here it indicates that ここにいられる is the reason for your feeling 嬉しい.

You could begin the sentence with わたしは, and a guy might use masculine ぼくは instead, but it can often be left out as implied.

You wouldn't have to change your wording depending on the gender of your audience.

Answer (score 2):

How about     :

> 私は今、ここにいる事が幸せ。

Answer (score 1):

> ここにいるだけですごくうれしい

which Google Translate has as 
"Very happy just to be here."

A little more formally:

> こちらにいるだけでとてもうれしいです

A Tokyo gal might say

> ここにいるからちょううれしいわ

And someone in Osaka might say

> ここにいるのでめっちゃうれしい

ちょう (超) means "very" or "extremely" and is Tokyo slang.

めっちゃ is Osaka slang for the same.  Google Translate suggests 'hella'

Comment: 大阪あたりでは「ここにおれてめっちゃうれしい」京都あたりでは「ここにいれてめっちゃうれしい」とか言うと思います（質問者は「ここに**が**いる」と書くくらいの初心者ですので方言より先に普通の言い方を教えてあげるほうが先かという気もしますが・・・)